# Hidden pins in CD4000.lib with LTspice

Tags: ltspice, spice

While working with the CD4000.lib in LTSpiceIV I came across the following:
A capacitor was discharged via a CMOS Schmitt trigger input. Analysis of this behavior revealed that LTSpice may not handle hidden pins correctly.

See for yourself:

The first case was the one where I noticed the behavior.

In the second case, I represented the discharge as an RC element.

In the third case I looked at the input filter stage of the CD40106 in the CD4000.lib (there is also a 100Meg resistance against VGND as expected. ) The net list of the subckt CD40_IN_S_1 was transferred into the current simulation and connected to GND and VDD.
During the simulation, of course (as it should be) the diodes struck and cut the negative voltage.

In the fourth case, input filter stage has been inserted again, but this time without connecting the diodes to VDD and GND.
During the simulation, exactly the behavior that caused me headaches became apparent.

This raises questions:

- What's wrong here?
- How are hidden pins used in LTspice?
- What has to be done in this case to get correct simulation results with the CD4000.lib?

Here is the asc file:

cut here ---

```
    Version 4
    SHEET 1 3772 2028
    WIRE -48 320 -352 320
    WIRE 48 320 -48 320
    WIRE 192 320 112 320
    WIRE 400 320 192 320
    WIRE 640 320 400 320
    WIRE -352 496 -352 320
    WIRE -48 496 -352 496
    WIRE 48 496 -48 496
    WIRE 192 496 112 496
    WIRE 400 496 192 496
    WIRE 656 496 400 496
    WIRE 768 496 736 496
    WIRE 560 624 560 576
    WIRE 560 704 560 624
    WIRE -352 864 -352 496
    WIRE -48 864 -352 864
    WIRE 48 864 -48 864
    WIRE 192 864 112 864
    WIRE 400 864 192 864
    WIRE 560 864 560 768
    WIRE 560 864 400 864
    WIRE 672 864 560 864
    WIRE 736 864 672 864
    WIRE 928 864 816 864
    WIRE 672 912 672 864
    WIRE 928 912 928 864
    WIRE 560 944 560 864
    WIRE 112 992 -240 992
    WIRE 144 992 112 992
    WIRE -240 1040 -240 992
    WIRE 672 1056 672 992
    WIRE 784 1056 672 1056
    WIRE 928 1056 928 976
    WIRE 928 1056 784 1056
    WIRE 560 1104 560 1008
    WIRE 784 1104 784 1056
    WIRE -240 1136 -240 1072
    WIRE 96 1136 -240 1136
    WIRE 144 1136 96 1136
    WIRE -240 1168 -240 1136
    WIRE 784 1168 784 1104
    WIRE 560 1328 560 1264
    WIRE -352 1488 -352 864
    WIRE -48 1488 -352 1488
    WIRE 48 1488 -48 1488
    WIRE 192 1488 112 1488
    WIRE 400 1488 192 1488
    WIRE 560 1488 560 1392
    WIRE 560 1488 400 1488
    WIRE 672 1488 560 1488
    WIRE 736 1488 672 1488
    WIRE 928 1488 816 1488
    WIRE 672 1536 672 1488
    WIRE 928 1536 928 1488
    WIRE 560 1584 560 1488
    WIRE -352 1632 -352 1488
    WIRE 672 1680 672 1616
    WIRE 784 1680 672 1680
    WIRE 928 1680 928 1600
    WIRE 928 1680 784 1680
    WIRE 560 1696 560 1648
    WIRE -352 1728 -352 1664
    WIRE 784 1728 784 1680
    WIRE 784 1792 784 1728
    FLAG -48 496 stimulus
    FLAG 192 496 response2
    FLAG 192 320 response1
    FLAG 192 864 response3
    FLAG 768 496 0
    FLAG -240 1168 0
    FLAG 784 1104 VGND
    FLAG 112 992 VDD
    FLAG 96 1136 VGND
    FLAG 560 1104 0
    FLAG 560 624 VDD
    FLAG -48 320 stimulus
    FLAG -48 864 stimulus
    FLAG -352 1728 0
    FLAG 192 1488 response4
    FLAG 784 1728 VGND
    FLAG -48 1488 stimulus
    SYMBOL cap 48 512 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName C1
    SYMATTR Value 2.2n
    SYMBOL cap 48 336 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName C3
    SYMATTR Value 2.2n
    SYMBOL diode 576 1008 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D1
    SYMATTR Value CD40DIO1
    SYMBOL diode 576 768 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D2
    SYMATTR Value CD40DIO1
    SYMBOL res 720 848 M90
    WINDOW 0 5 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 27 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R1
    SYMATTR Value 10k
    SYMBOL cap 944 912 M0
    SYMATTR InstName C4
    SYMATTR Value {Cval}
    SYMBOL res 656 896 R0
    SYMATTR InstName R2
    SYMATTR Value 1e8
    SYMBOL cap 48 880 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName C5
    SYMATTR Value 2.2n
    SYMBOL Dig_Add\\CD4xxx\\cd40106b 688 272 R0
    WINDOW 38 -118 145 Left 2
    WINDOW 39 -118 117 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName U2
    SYMATTR SpiceLine VDD={Versorgungsspannung}  SPEED={SPEED}  TRIPDT={TRIPDT}
    SYMBOL res 640 512 R270
    WINDOW 0 27 56 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName R3
    SYMATTR Value 100Meg
    SYMBOL MiniSyms4\\voltage- -240 1056 R0
    WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
    WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName V3
    SYMATTR Value {Versorgungsspannung}
    SYMBOL MiniSyms4\\voltage- -352 1648 R0
    WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
    WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName V1
    SYMATTR Value PULSE({Versorgungsspannung} 0 0.025 0.0001)
    SYMBOL res 720 1472 M90
    WINDOW 0 5 56 VBottom 2
    WINDOW 3 27 56 VTop 2
    SYMATTR InstName R4
    SYMATTR Value 10k
    SYMBOL cap 944 1536 M0
    SYMATTR InstName C2
    SYMATTR Value {Cval}
    SYMBOL res 656 1520 R0
    SYMATTR InstName R5
    SYMATTR Value 1e8
    SYMBOL cap 48 1504 R270
    WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
    WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
    SYMATTR InstName C6
    SYMATTR Value 2.2n
    SYMBOL diode 576 1648 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D3
    SYMATTR Value CD40DIO1
    SYMBOL diode 576 1392 R180
    WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
    WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
    SYMATTR InstName D4
    SYMATTR Value CD40DIO1
    TEXT -312 584 Left 2 !.param Versorgungsspannung=15\n.param SPEED=1.0\n.param TRIPDT=5e-9
    TEXT 672 784 Left 2 !.MODEL CD40DIO1 D(Is=1e-12 Rs=100)
    TEXT 976 880 Left 2 !.param Cval = 1.8e-12*5/{Versorgungsspannung}*{SPEED}\n.param vt1=2.5/5\n.param vh1=0.4/5\n.param gain=(1/{Versorgungsspannung})
    TEXT 664 624 Left 4 ;Schmitt-input; 2.9V/2.1V @5   CD40_IN_S_1
    TEXT 1408 1144 Left 2 ;see CD4000.lib
    TEXT -204 1750 Left 2 !.tran .5
    TEXT 440 848 Left 2 ;in
    TEXT 440 1472 Left 2 ;in
    TEXT 864 1472 Left 2 ;out10
    TEXT 872 848 Left 2 ;out10
    TEXT 912 320 Left 2 ;cd40106b.asy is linked to cd4000.lib
    TEXT 656 416 Left 2 ;should be hidden pins ( see parameter window: "SpiceModel VDD 0"
    TEXT 672 688 Left 2 ;input filter part \nreengineered from .subckt CD40106, .subckt CD40_IN_S_1
    TEXT -304 928 Left 2 ;Here (hidden) pins are explicitly connectet to VDD and VGND
    TEXT 1048 1080 Left 2 ;response3 is clamped by diodes D1, D2.
    TEXT 904 480 Left 2 ;RC with Tau=2.2n*100Meg gives the same response\n--> where are these 100Meg's ...
    TEXT 712 1000 Left 2 ;...here.
    TEXT 680 1248 Left 2 ;without diodes: response4 = response2
    TEXT 680 1328 Left 4 ;What is wrong with case 1 and case 3
    TEXT -256 288 Left 4 ;case 1:
    TEXT -288 824 Left 4 ;case 3:
    TEXT -264 456 Left 4 ;case 2:
    TEXT -264 1448 Left 4 ;case 4:
    RECTANGLE Normal 1632 1168 400 576 2
    RECTANGLE Normal 1632 1792 400 1200 2
```

cut here ---

[image: simulation schematic]

[image: simulation results]

Comment: Your `.asc` file is useless without the proper `.asy` used in the schematic (LTspice complains about missing `Point`, `cd40106b`, `voltage-`), or possible `.sub`, or `.mod` (subcircuit, or model) files.

Comment: I have removed the Point symbols from the schematic.

Comment: What about `cd40106b` and `voltage-`? The point is that if you want to send your schematic to someone else, you have to make sure that that person will have *everything* the schematic implies, because that person might not have what you have on your computer. That's why there's a good reason some say that a project should have its own folder, where you can copy any external symbols, libraries, etc, then simply archive the folder (`.zip` being a good choice, almost universal). Don't forget to ilnk the symbols, models, and libraries to those in the project's folder, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions.

The spice model I use comes from the library CD4000.lib. The cd40106b.asy symbol indicates CD4000.lib as the location of the model. In CD4000.lib you find ".SUBCKT CD40106B A Y VDD VGND vdd1={vdd} speed1={speed} tripdt1={tripdt}" ... so a model with 4 ports.

Connections A and Y are visually present in the symbol.

The VDD and VGND connections are set to VDD and 0 via the symbol parameters in the SpiceModel attribute (see case 1).

Further you find the input filter: "XIN1 A A Ai VDD VGND CD40_IN_S_1 vdd2={vdd1} speed2={speed1} tripdt2={tripdt1}"...

Under.subckt CD40_IN_S_1 you find the netlist ...

**OH - I GOT IT: You find**

```
    * Schmitt-input; 2.9V/2.1V @5V
    .SUBCKT CD40_IN_S_1 in out VDD VGND vdd3={vdd2} speed3={speed2} tripdt3={tripdt2} 
    .param Cval = 1.8e-12*5/{vdd3}*{speed3}
    .param vt1=2.5/5
    .param vh1=0.4/5
    .param gain=(1/{vdd3})
    *
    *D1 0 in CD40DIO1 
    *D2 in VDD CD40DIO1
    R1 in out10 10k
    C1 out10 VGND {Cval}
    R2 in VGND 1e8
    * E1 out20 0 out10 VGND {gain}
    B1 out20 0 V=LIMIT(0,V(out10,VGND)*{gain},1)
    AE1 out20 0 0 0 0 0 0 out 0 SMITH vt={vt1} vh={vh1} vhigh=1 tripdt={tripdt3}
    .ends
    *
```

**!!!! with commented out diodes.**

So the model used can be seen in case 4. To simulate the real behavior of the CD40106, the diodes must be present. They limit the amplitude of the input voltage to VCC+0.3V and GND-0.3V.

But attention: A pin compatible 6-way Schmitt Trigger MM74C914 has a different input protection circuit and allows VCC+25V and GND-25V. The model would have to be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You must DC bias to Vdd/2 whenever AC coupled

Comment: I could if I wanted to, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: The diode clamp needs to charge when swing exceeds rails and if input is not > 2/3Vdd then output is static

Comment: In the simulation results it can be seen that the step response behind the capacitors is a negative deflection down to -15V. If the diodes are connected as in case 3, the negative voltage must therefore be limited to the flux voltage of D2. That is also the case.
The question is why this does not happen in case 1, although the same circuit is present there.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like the CD40106 model you are using does not attempt to model the behavior of the input ESD diodes. This is not uncommon. Many SPICE models ignore behavior that is outside the normal operating range of a device. In this case, the author of the model didn't expect (or care) that the input voltage might be below ground
2. I don't know what you mean by "hidden pins". SPICE doesn't care about the pins of an IC package, it cares only about the circuit elements that are part of the simulated circuitry. SPICE can't simulate elements or behavior that you didn't include in the circuit.
3. Realise first that you **can not** get "correct" simulation results. Every simulation is a model of the real world, and all models are wrong. (Thanks, George Box.) You can search for a model of the 40106 that includes the ESD diodes, but that model might not be exactly like the physical part you have in your hand. You can characterize (i.e. measure the I/V curves) the input protection diodes on your physical part and add the diode model yourself, adjusting parameters so the model matches the real world. Or, you can build the circuit and see how it behaves in the real world. Be advised that relying on any repeatable, specific behavior of the ESD diodes is a bad idea.